# SQL Calculating balance based on inventory and transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a stored procedure that calculates a users inventory status.

Imagine the following table called `user_inventory` with many numbered columns:

```
id_inventory    id_user    0    1    2    3
------------    -------    -    -    -    -
           2          4    5    0    14   21
```

And another one called `user_transactions`

```
id_tran    id_user   0    1    2    3
-------    -------   -    -    -    -
     54          4   1    0    3    7
     55          4   2    0    9    8
     56          4   1    0    2    4
```

What I would like is a way to calculate the remaining inventory status for each column after subtracting a sum of all of the users transactions, like so:

```
id_availableInventory    id_user    0    1    2    3
---------------------    -------    -    -    -    -
                    2          4    1    0    0    2
```

The additional obstacle is that there are columns labeled from 0 to 499.

I have tried to use a while loop and update one column at a time using dynamic sql and SUM(), but had both scope and performance issues - and I'm not sure if that was a good approach to this problem. I am using SQL Server 2012.

```
DECLARE @counter int  
DECLARE @userid int
DECLARE @amount int
DECLARE @sum int
declare @sql nvarchar(1000)
SET @counter = 0  
SET @userid = 4 
WHILE @counter < 500  
BEGIN   
    set @sql = 'SELECT @amount = [' + CAST(@counter AS nvarchar) + '] FROM user_inventory WHERE ID_User = ' +CAST(@userid AS nvarchar)
    EXEC(@sql)
    set @sql = 'SELECT @sum = SUM([' + CAST(@counter AS nvarchar) + ']) FROM user_transactions WHERE ID_User = ' +CAST(@userid AS nvarchar)
    EXEC(@sql)
    set @sql = 'UPDATE user_availableinventory SET [' + CAST(@counter AS nvarchar) + '] = @amount - @sum WHERE ID_User = ' +CAST(@userid AS nvarchar)
    EXEC(@sql)
    SET @counter = @counter + 1  
END
```

This returned `Must declare the scalar variable "@amount".`multiple times. 
I am aware this is an ugly approach, any suggestions to this problem are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Imagining a table with many numbers columns is rather close to a nightmare for me.  You should fix your data structure.  Whatever is going into those columns should probably be in separate rows.

Comment: So instead of this structure, one with 500 rows per user account with columns like "id, inventoryID, amount" would be a faster and better one?

Comment: This isn't anything resembling a reasonable data structure for a relational database. Columns 0, 1, 2, 3???? And no idea why you are doing this in a loop. This should be a single update statement. You desperately need to either fix this data structure or consider using a noSQL type of storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are using the variables outside the scope of the variable. Query strings are executed as a separate session, so you need to declare the variables inside the query string.

You can try this by declaring the variables inside the query string

```
DECLARE @counter int  
DECLARE @userid int
declare @sql nvarchar(1000)
SET @counter = 0  
SET @userid = 4 
WHILE @counter < 500  
BEGIN   
    set @sql = '
    DECLARE @sum int  
    DECLARE @amount int

    SELECT 
        @amount = [' + CAST(@counter AS nvarchar) + '] 
        FROM user_inventory WHERE ID_User = ' +CAST(@userid AS nvarchar)+'

    SELECT 
        @sum = SUM([' + CAST(@counter AS nvarchar) + ']) 
        FROM user_transactions WHERE ID_User = ' +CAST(@userid AS nvarchar)+'

    UPDATE user_availableinventory SET [' + CAST(@counter AS nvarchar) + '] = @amount - @sum WHERE ID_User = ' +CAST(@userid AS nvarchar)

    EXEC(@sql)
    SET @counter = @counter + 1  

END
```

Comment: This fixes the error but doesn't address the horrific design of this disaster. You still deserve a +1 but wow....I feel bad for the OP that they are going to have to work with this.

Comment: It's too late to discuss the design issues when you already have data in the tables

Comment: This achieves what I set out to do, but the process is extremely slow (13 seconds). I will need to change my entire structure. Fortunetaly, this structure is still in design and I have time to rework it before it hits production.

Comment: I would disagree with that entirely. Just because data is in the tables does not mean you are stuck with a deign, it is just more complicated to fix it.

Comment: Changing the structure will definitely improve the Performance